# Sound playback produces unwanted noise ("popping", etc.)

Tags: 11.10, sound, realtek

So, I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop and everything went smoothly, except for the sound.

I consulted the Ubuntu Wiki and several other support sites, telling me to edit the ALSA configuration file and add a line to disable power management.

Before I did that though, I ran across a script that would collect information about my system and put it on the ALSA project page.

The output: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b39cc6b1a7b17ba2f12fc0c74a4beae0855e6d4e

There is a line that says that power save was already disabled. It's as follows: "snd_hda_intel: power_save=0", so I did not edit the file because it'd be useless.

So, since that option is apparently out of question, what else can I do?

Some additional information:
-Card: Realtek ALC662

Comment: In a completely unrelated problem I had, in which my network connection would slow down after a few minutes and was advised to use wicd to manage my connections (which worked) I can no longer hear sound problems since I started using it. I don't know why.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,